# cannot import name 'Product' from 'products.models'

Tags: python, django-3.2

I am new to django, i am following a tutorial i do same things but got an error

Im trying to make view for products app this is products.models

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Product(models.Model):
    title       = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
    price       = models.TextField()
```

products.views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Product

def product_detail_view(request):
    obj = Product.objects.get(id=1)
    context = {
        'title':obj.title,
        'description':obj.description
    }
    return render(request, "product/detail.html", context)
```

prouducts .urls

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('product',views.product_view_detail, name='Home'),
]
```

urls.py

```
from new1.settings import MEDIA_ROOT
from django import urls
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from pages import views
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('pages.urls'), name='Home'),
    path('product',include('products.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

I got this error `cannot import name 'Product' from 'products.models'`
it works before i add products views

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "g:\64-bit\new folder\py38 64bit\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
   self.run()
 File "g:\64-bit\new folder\py38 64bit\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
   self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
 File "C:\Users\aram\.virtualenvs\cfeproj-ldwjYLGf\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
   fn(*args, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Users\aram\.virtualenvs\cfeproj-ldwjYLGf\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
   self.check(display_num_errors=True)
 File "C:\Users\aram\.virtualenvs\cfeproj-ldwjYLGf\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 419, in check
   all_issues = checks.run_checks(
 File "C:\Users\aram\.virtualenvs\cfeproj-ldwjYLGf\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
   new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
 File "C:\Users\aram\.virtualenvs\cfeproj-ldwjYLGf\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
   return check_resolver(resolver)
 File "C:\Users\aram\.virtualenvs\cfeproj-ldwjYLGf\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
   return check_method()
 File "C:\Users\aram\.virtualenvs\cfeproj-ldwjYLGf\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 412, in check
   for pattern in self.url_patterns:
 File "C:\Users\aram\.virtualenvs\cfeproj-ldwjYLGf\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
   res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
 File "C:\Users\aram\.virtualenvs\cfeproj-ldwjYLGf\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 598, in url_patterns
   patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
 File "C:\Users\aram\.virtualenvs\cfeproj-ldwjYLGf\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
   res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
 File "C:\Users\aram\.virtualenvs\cfeproj-ldwjYLGf\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 591, in urlconf_module
   return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
 File "g:\64-bit\new folder\py38 64bit\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
   return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
 File "C:\Users\aram\Desktop\cfeproj\new1\urls.py", line 33, in <module>
   path('product',include('products.urls')),
 File "C:\Users\aram\.virtualenvs\cfeproj-ldwjYLGf\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
   urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
 File "g:\64-bit\new folder\py38 64bit\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
   return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
 File "C:\Users\aram\Desktop\cfeproj\products\urls.py", line 3, in <module>
   from . import views
 File "C:\Users\aram\Desktop\cfeproj\products\views.py", line 2, in <module>
   from .models import Product
ImportError: cannot import name 'Product' from 'products.models' (C:\Users\aram\Desktop\cfeproj\products\models.py)
```

Comment: Does you directory have `__init__.py` file ? And have you add your app to `INSTALLED_APP`

Comment: yes, i have `__init__.py` but its empty and i add products to installed app, the error show on when i want to build views products before it products worked and i could add data to it

Comment: Can you add the full traceback you get when the error occurs?

Comment: @norie I add full traceback

Answer (score 1):

At your settings add 'products' at installed app then makemigrations and migrate the
migrations then try again